# How to create play heroku procfile?

Tags: java, heroku, playframework

I am following the directions here

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/8/29/play/

but I do `play run` and then `git push heroku master` but a procfile is not found.

```
-----> No Procfile found. Will use process: 
       play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
```

1. How do I explicitly create a procfile?
2. The instructions seem to indicate that I should push to `heroku master` while the app is running. Am I reading that wrong?
3. Where can I specify `$PORT` and `$PLAY_OPTS` for mydomain.herokuapp.com?
4. Is it better to just modify the values for `%prod` in application.conf?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to create a file named Procfile in the root of your project and for Play it should contain

```
web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
```

When you then deploy your application the $PORT and $PLAY_OPTS will be set by heroku when the application is started.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was just not comprehending the need to create a file since it was 2am and my brain was melted. A slight change in the docs to explicitly call out the need to create a "file named Procfile in the root of your play app" would be my suggestion to the Heroku keepers.

Comment: For play 2.0 you need a different procfile. See: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ProductionHeroku

Comment: @notbrain How do you set the Heroku defined PORT variable yourself

Comment: It may be that this has changed recently, but `play run` would not work for me. Instead:
`target/start -Dhttp.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS` 
worked as per: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797106/bash-play-command-not-found-when-trying-heroku-for-the-first-time

Answer (score 10):

1. Creating a Procfile is as simple as it sounds. Just create a file called Procfile and declare your process types and commands. More information is here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
   In this case, you didn't provide a Procfile so Heroku just used the standard Play process.  It's best practice to explitly provide a Procfile in case this default changes in the future.
2. No, you are not reading that wrong. To upload a new version of your app you perform a git push to heroku.
3. The $PORT variable is set internally by Heroku. No need to set it. The $PLAY_OPTS variable is set in your app space when you first push your Play app to Heroku. You can see it using the heroku command line. More information on that command line is here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command

To view your app configuration:

```
$ heroku config
```

To change $PLAY_OPTS:

```
$ heroku config:remove PLAY_OPTS
$ heroku config:add PLAY_OPTS=...
```

By default, heroku will run Play apps under the prod framework id. You can change this in your Procfile or in the $PLAY_OPTS variable. The only important thing here is that your app run in PROD mode on heroku (note that mode is different from framework id). Heroku cannot run Play apps in DEV mode.

Comment: Re #2 - since I am now set straight about the Procfile, my question about needing to push it *while play is running locally* is now deemed absurd. I *was* reading it wrong, a simple push to heroku with changes will trigger a deployment, regardless of running. For some reason I thought the Procfile was something that was created by play when launched.

Answer (score 8):

It will considerably depend on the play version you're using. I checked the docs and found the following `Procfile`s for each of the given versions:

- **1.x**

  ```
  web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
  ```
- **2.0**

  ```
  web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS}
  ```
- **2.2.0**

  ```
  web: bin/<your-appname> -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true
  ```
- **2.2.1**

  ```
  web: target/universal/stage/bin/<your-appname> -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true
  ```

For more information for the specific version check this URL:

```
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ProductionHeroku
```

Make sure you replace `2.2.1` with whatever version you're using.