# How to set framework id in a Heroku deployed Play! application

Tags: heroku, playframework

my question is simple. I want to set the play framework 'id' in my heroku deployed copy, different than the one I have locally.

To do so, I followed [this reference page](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/ids) by running 'heroku run play id' from my local computer. However, that didn't work, as if I executed again the same command, it would tell me that the id was still empty.

So, I researched in StackOverflow a bit, and got to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633283/how-to-create-play-heroku-procfile) in which I understand, according to an answer, that I can do so by modifying the PLAY_OPTS variable, but I dont really get it... So if someone could explain it to me clearly, I would really appreciate it!

Thanks a lot in advance,

Pepillo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the `PLAY_OPTS` environment variable with:

```
heroku config
```

Which should include:

```
PLAY_OPTS           => --%prod -Dprecompiled=true
```

You can change that with something like:

```
heroku config:add PLAY_OPTS="--%foo -Dprecompiled=true"
```

But you will have to make sure that you also tell the Play app not to try and listen on the jpda port or it will fail to start on Heroku.

Comment: How do I tell Play not to listen on the jpda port? I'm having this exact problem.

Comment: I didn't listen for that port in dev mode neither, so Im not sure... but I guess that if you write '$dev.jpda.port = 8000' instead of 'jpda.port=8000' (or whatever actual lines you had) in the application.conf, it should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Heroku config (heroku config) and add PLAY_OPTS to your liking.

```
heroku config:add PLAY_OPTS="--%prod -Dprecompiled=true"
```

After, just change your Procfile to something like :

```
web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
```

Comment: You are just telling me what's the default for a Play! application, and what I asked for was for actually making a custom  one! Or I didn't understand you correctly...