# How to set Procfile in Heroku in PlayFramework

Tags: heroku, playframework

Now I am trying to deploy PlayApplication, but unfortunately my deploy failed. And the error code is H10, so probably I assume the problem is setting files because my database setting must be true as I can connect database by using the created username, password and URL.
And in my understanding, Procfile just shows a command to be run toward dynos and in tutorials, in terms of Java the procfile is like this:
`web: java -jar target/helloworld.jar`

However, in my application, the Procfile is `web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS}  -Dconfig.file=conf/application_prod.conf` where conf/application_prod.conf is the path to the setting file.   Is this Procfile right?
My play version is 2.2.1 and  [the official document](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ProductionHeroku) says `web: target/universal/stage/bin/retailos -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}` is good and I can also use the option `-Dconfig.file=` and then you can indicate where the setting file is. This means `web: target/universal/stage/bin/retailos -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=trueBut -Dconfig.file=conf/application_prod.conf`. But it does not work well.
And there are many candidates about the right way being also indicted by [How to create play heroku procfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633283/how-to-create-play-heroku-procfile).
I am really confused. I already have written all DB settings into application_prod.conf, so I prefer to use `-Dconfig.file=`.
What is exactly the true one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `-Dconfig.file` and similar is definitely a good idea, you do not need to set all config parameters in your Procfile.

The reason it doesn't work is probably because you're using a file path for your config file, which to my knowledge doesn't work when the application is deployed as a jar. Try this instead:

```
-Dconfig.resource=application_prod.conf
```